# Python if statement failing to match words from array 'in' string

Tags: python, python-2.7, reddit

So I'm playing with a reddit API to monitor a sales subreddit, and I have this section of code:

```
if(any(w.lower() in re.search('%s(.*)%s' % ("[h]", "[w]"), i['data']['title'].lower()).group(1).lower() for w in wants)
                                and i['data']['id'] not in urls):
                                        urls[i['data']['id']] = [i['data']['title'],i['data']['url']]
```

Effectively, it takes the reddit post title, and selects all text between [w] and [h] tags within that title. It then checks to see if any of the words defined in the 'wants' list appear in the title, if so, it adds the title and reddit link to an array.

An example I've tested on would be the word *ergodox* in the wants list, and the post title being *[us-wi] [h] ergodox infinity (w/ sip socket mod) [w] paypal*. But the post didn't get added to the array, presumable because the if(any...) statement above never validated to be true, but I don't see why.

Another question for once that's fixed, sometimes [h] and [w] will appear the opposite way around, is there any short way to allow for that? Or will it require an *or* extension to the if statement?

Thanks in advance :)

**EDIT** for courtesy of the comment, an attempt at simplifying which didn't work either:

```
for w in wants:
    if w.lower() in i['data']['title'].lower() and i['data']['id'] not in urls:
    urls[i['data']['id']] = [[i['data']['title'],i['data']['url']]
```

Comment: I would suggest breaking it down outside the generator expression (or list comprehension) to make things a bit more readable. In the process of doing so, you will end up simplifying your code and making the bug more obvious.

Comment: @RafaelBarros I did try that earlier, I will edit the post and supply the code I tried, it too didn't work...

Comment: what's in `wants`?

Comment: Are you aware that the `[]` characters have special meaning in regular expressions?

Comment: @RafaelBarros wants is populated by a file, containing a word or phrase on each line, it's read into the list using readlines(). Could it be tacking on some garbage for new lines?

Comment: In your simplified example, what are the values of `w`, `i['data']['title']`, `i['data']['id']` and `urls`?

Comment: @AviateX14 it might contain empty spaces or line breaks, try doing a strip with  `w.strip().lower()`

Comment: @JohnGordon w would be 'ergodox', i['data']['title'] would be '[us-wi] [h] ergodox infinity (w/ sip socket mod) [w] paypal' and i['data']['id'] would be a unique id, '4aje' etc.

Comment: I would suggest you to make a unit test and make tiny modifications to solve your problem

Comment: @RafaelBarros It's the simplest things! I feel silly for posting, all sorted, could you drop your comment in as an answer? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try doing `w.strip().lower()` to clear the variable of unwanted spaces and linebreaks.

effectively:

```
for w in wants:
    if w.strip().lower() in i['data']['title'].lower() and i['data']['id'] not in urls:
    urls[i['data']['id']] = [[i['data']['title'],i['data']['url']]
```

Comment: Thanks, worked a treat, don't suppose you have anything to say on my other more minor point? It's no biggie if not... "Another question for once that's fixed, sometimes [h] and [w] will appear the opposite way around, is there any short way to allow for that? Or will it require an or extension to the if statement?"

Comment: @AviateX14 I would highly suggest making a second regex to keep things cleaner and extending the if statement. It can be done by making the regex match either way but it would add complexity regex.